# Django 1.11 can't connect to Postgres on RDS

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I created a new EC2 Instance with Postgres on RDS.  I confirmed that I can connect from the EC2 instance to the database using psql without any issue which means my security settings are fine.

However, when I try to run `manage.py runserver` or `manage.py dbshell` (from the virtualenv) Django hangs then eventually gives a timeout error:

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out   Is the server
>   running on host "whatever.rds.amazonaws.com"
>   (172.xxx.xxx.xxx) and accepting   TCP/IP connections on port 5342?
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/ubuntu/Env/xxxx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 363, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>
> File "/home/ubuntu/Env/ss2017/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 355, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>
> File "/home/ubuntu/Env/ss2017/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 283, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>
> File "/home/ubuntu/Env/ss2017/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 330, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>
> File "/home/ubuntu/Env/ss2017/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/dbshell.py",
>   line 22, in handle
>       connection.client.runshell()
>
> File "/home/ubuntu/Env/ss2017/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/client.py",
>   line 66, in runshell
>       DatabaseClient.runshell_db(self.connection.get_connection_params())
>
> File "/home/ubuntu/Env/ss2017/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/client.py",
>   line 58, in runshell_db
>       subprocess.check_call(args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['psql', '-U', 'db_name',
>   '-h', 'whatever.rds.amazonaws.com', '-p', '5342', 'user_name']'
>   returned non-zero exit status 2

I tried creating a new copy of the Django app to see if there were perhaps corrupt files involved, and I played with some changes to my `settings.py` file, but no luck.

Any ideas?

**Edit**:

Settings.py (the important bits)

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1', 'compute.amazonaws.com']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'whatever.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5342',
    }
}
```

Comment: so doing `psql -U db_name -h something.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 user name` from the EC2 CLI connects with no issues?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy - Yup, I can connect without any issues using the psql command from the EC2 CLI.  I am thoroughly confused!

Comment: do you have something along the lines of `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS", "settings")` in your `manage.py` file? also have you tried changing the host to `localhost`

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy The app runs fine on localhost on my dev machine, and yes, I do have the environ settings in manage.py.  I am busy setting up postgres on the EC2 instance to see if I can connect that way.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Your suggestion of testing localhost helped me - please see my answer to what caused the error.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved adding EC2 instance ip as custom TCP rule in the security group associated to the rds db, now migrate works like a charm. I'm just starting with aws, do you think it's safe?

Comment: @Paolo I used AWS for a different postgres system and we did something similar by changing the security groups until it all clicked.  We didn't find any security issues, but I won't claim to be an expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a local postgres database on the EC2 server to see if any errors come up. When I tried to run `makemigrations` or `migrate` to set up the database I got a "relation does not exist" error.  The stack trace pointed to a line in one of my views that looked something like this:

```
some_queryset = Model.objects.all()
some_queryset.delete() # <--- this line was the problem
```

Even though this is technically an acceptable way to delete all entries in a given table, Django (on the server) did not like the fact that the relationships of the given model did not exist.

I commented out the line and was able to connect to the database without any issues.

So for future readers - if your Django app hangs on `runserver`, but you can reach the RDS database from the EC2 instance, try setting up a local database to check for any issues.

Answer (score 0):

`exit status 2` usually means you've called psql with the wrong arguments. For me, a psql authentication error also triggered this exit code. My problem ended up being a typo in the DBPASSWORD environment variable that `settings.DATABASES['default']` was using.